# Is there a way of storing an query formula in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Linux can store functions, which can easily be called using the `function` system. If I wish to write several if statements however that should use the same reasoning, can this be done? For example:

```
if [ x == 1 ]
then
  ...
fi
```

If I need to use the `x == 1` for umpteen formulas and vary all, can a block formula hold the equation so that I only need to make one modification instead of needing to modify all of them please?

Comment: you mean that you just need to change the left operand like `if [ x == 1 ] .... elif [ y == 1 ] ... elif [ z == 1 ]` ?

Comment: Can you be a bit more generic and show us with some actual code examples on what you are looking for? Are you looking for string comparison (or)  in arithmetic context? It is not clear

Comment: The code in this case is  if [ $((RANDOM % 10)) -le 7 ]  which is used 3 times. I am entirely unsure of the RANDOM factor however, and even know that I may use it more (4 or 5 times). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can just wrap your logic in a function and use the function as the condition in the `if`:

```
my_check() {
    [ "$x" -eq 1 ]
}

if my_check
then
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi
```

This is taking advantage that the exit status of a shell function is the exit status of the last executed command. So if "$x" equals one the return status of `my_check` will be `0` (ie. success) and then you will enter the main branch. Otherwise exit status will be `1` (ie. failure) and then you will enter the alternate branch.

You could have multiple functions, one for each condition:

```
check_a() {
    [ "$x" -eq 1 ]
}

check_b() {
    [ "$x" -eq 2 ]
}

check_c() {
    [ "$y" -eq 1 ]
}

if check_a && check_c
then
    echo "a and c are true"
elif check_b && check_c
then
    ...
elif check_c
then
    ...
else
    ...
fi
```

Comment: A very nice idea, but the RANDOM concept in this case needs to work each time. Could a similar system be done with [ `Test` -eq 1 ] please?

Comment: @HugMyster: In your case, define the function as `checkRandom() { [ $((RANDOM % 10)) -le 7 ] ; }` and use it in condition as `if checkRandom; then`

Comment: That is absolutely perfect - thank you very much! :o)